# Можно ли разместить секции в UICollectionView в 2 столбца?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Пишу календарь на базе `UICollectionView`. Один месяц - одна секция. В картинке отображен вид для iPhone.

Можно ли как то отображать секции в два столбца - по две секции на одной линии (отображение для iPad)

[image: iPhone]

Answer (score 1):

Да, это можно сделать. Вы должны указать `scrollingDirection`: `[myFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но решение не подходит. Если я буду показывать 12 месяцев, то это 12 секций - 6 рядов (по вертикали) и по 2 секции в одном ряде на ширину экрана (по горизонтали). Скролл должен быть вертикальным

Comment: Как идея для начала движения, может быть вам сделать так:  collectionView с двумя ячейками в ряду, но внутрь каждой ячейки добавить новую collectionView которая будет отображать месяц.

Comment: других вариантов решения не вижу, так и сделаю

Answer (score 0):

Расположить секции в 2 столбца можно двум способами:

1. Использовать вложенные коллекции, когда ячейка первой коллекции содержит коллекцию как `subview`. В этом случае получаем следующие проблемы:

   - перегруженный UI - будут заметны лаги при первом запуске
   - проблемы с `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` для вложенной коллекции, так как у всех хедеров и футеров будет одинаковый `indexPath`
   - проблемы с `cellForItemAtIndexPath` для вложенной коллекции - метод не вызовется второй раз, если уже есть отрисованная ячейка с таким же `indexPath`, ячейка просто скопируется без обновления данных.

Все эти проблемы можно решить программно, но получится очень некрасивый и запутаный код.

2. Вместо двух секций сделать одну широкую секцию - ячейки двух месяцев в одной секции. Для разделения месяцев можно использовать пустые прозрачные ячейки